# Result to function javascript array

Tags: javascript, php

I have this script in javascript, where once been a date 04/13/2017, it is returned instead a cliclo like this:

-

Now I would like the result to be saved as an array, so you can use later.

This is the code, I also accept tips on how to improve it.

```
var rounds = ['s', 'p', 'm', 'n', 'r'];

function pippo(giorno, mese, anno, nGiorni) {
    var ret = new Array();
    var data = new Date(anno, mese-1, giorno+1);
  for (var i=0;i<nGiorni;i++) {
  //alert(rounds[i%(rounds.length)]);
    ret[i] = {'id':parseInt(Math.random()*1000),'title':rounds[i%                               (rounds.length)],'start':data.toISOString().substr(0,10)+'T23:59:00','tipo':'t5'}
  data = new Date(data.getFullYear(),data.getMonth(),data.getDate()+1);
  }
 return ret;
}


pluto = pippo(13, 04, 2017, 16);

for (i=0;i<pluto.length;i++) {

 var str = pluto[i]['start']+' '+pluto[i]['title'];
 document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = document.getElementById('toto').innerHTML + str + '<br/>';

}


<div id="result"></div>
```

I serve an array like this:

```
$event_array[] = array(

    'id' => $random,

    'title' => $rounds[$i%count($rounds)],

    'start' => $nextDate."T23:59:00",

    'tipo' => 't5'

    );
```

The script in question works in this way: The user saves a date initial then a cycle for n times is generated (must decide in function) increasing by 1 the initial date example:

initial date: 2017-04-13

```
var rounds = [ 's', 'p', 'm', 'n', 'r'];
```

2017-04-13T23: 59: 00 s
2017-04-14T23: 59: 00 p
2017-04-15T23: 59: 00 m
2017-04-16T23: 59: 00 No
2017-04-17T23: 59: 00 r
2017-04-18T23: 59: 00 s
2017-04-19T23: 59: 00 p
2017-04-20T23: 59: 00 m
2017-04-21T23: 59: 00 No
2017-04-22T23: 59: 00 r
2017-04-23T23: 59: 00 s
2017-04-24T23: 59: 00 p
2017-04-25T23: 59: 00 m
2017-04-26T23: 59: 00 No
2017-04-27T23: 59: 00 r
2017-04-28T23: 59: 00 s

This thing I set that has to count to 16.
[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/sixdas/x7yby3ah/3/)
I hope I was clear.
date

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. It seems like you already have a function. What do you mean by "has to count to 16"?

Comment: It is already the script works properly, I instead of displaying result in div

2017-04-13T23: 59: 00 s
2017-04-14T23: 59: 00 p
etc ...

I would like to save a similar array to that posted in php

Comment: Do you want to save that array in database or something via calling php side? If so use ajax. But as Fafl says its still unclear :D good luck

Comment: not the result, I would like to save it as json array in localStorage